# Reducing Haskell expressions

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, reduction

Hi I am a Haskell newbie and mostly reading from [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) and [Hutton](https://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/book.html). 
Recently I came across this snippet where the Functor instance of 
a State monad, expressed as:

```
instance Functor (State st) where
    fmap f m = State $ \st -> let (a, s) = runState m st in (f a, s)
```

This can be reduced to:

```
instance Functor (State st) where 
    fmap f m = State $ (\(a,s) -> (f a,s)) . runState m
```

Can anyone explain the workflow behind this reduction?

Also what are some good resources/advice on how to learn such reduction techniques?

Comment: The first version is actually incomplete, it should be `let (a, s) = runState m st` (Or, in the pattern, `fmap f (State m)`. Does that clarify things? — Note that none of this will work in recent GHC, since `State` isn't a simple `newtype` anymore but defined in terms of a monad transformer. (Which is easy to account for: just replace `State` with `state`.)

Comment: Hi, I made an error when writing the snippet. Thanks for your reply. 
Could you explain what you mean by in the pattern fmap (State m)?

Also just plain curiosity.

Comment: Well, before building the "new State object" with the fmapped value, you deconstruct the original one. Again that doesn't work in the standard library now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If any of the concepts I bring up (such as lambda functions) are unclear, read about them in LYAH and play around a little with them in `ghci`. Then come back to this reply again and everything should clear up a bit!

One thing that might be confusing if you are coming from other programming languages is that in Haskell, you can take a function such as

```
runState
```

and add one argument

```
runState m
```

and it will still be a valid function. If you then add a second argument, like so:

```
runState m st
```

it will finally compute a value. This means that if `runState` is a function of two arguments, then `runState m` is a function of one argument and can be treated like any other function of one argument.

---

The important bit in your example is

```
\st -> let (a, s) = runState m st in (f a, s)
```

which can be turned into

```
(\(a,s) -> (f a,s)) . runState m
```

using the operator for function composition, `(.)`.

---

The first step to understanding how that is possible is recognising that a `let…in` expression can be rewritten in a lambda form. This means that

```
let y = f x in expr
```

can be written as

```
(\y -> expr) (f x)
```

Both of those lines will bind the name `y` to the value of `f x`, which is really all we need of a `let…in` expression.

If you apply that knowledge to

```
\st -> let (a, s) = runState m st in (f a, s)
```

you will see that it can be rewritten as

```
\st -> (\(a, s) -> (f a, s)) (runState m st)
```

and we're halfway there!

---

The definition of function composition is this:

```
f . g = \x -> f (g x)
```

This means that any time you have something that looks like `\x -> f (g x)` you can replace it with just `f . g`.

Well, in this case we *do* have something that looks like that! If we say that

```
f = \(a, s) -> (f a, s)
g = runState m
x = st
```

We see that

```
\st -> (\(a, s) -> (f a, s)) (runState m st)
\x  -> f                     (g          x)
```

is no more than function composition waiting to happen. So we can turn it into

```
f . g
```

which was, with our definitions of `f` and `g`,

```
f                     . g
(\(a, s) -> (f a, s)) . (runState m)
```

and you are allowed to drop the parentheses around `runState m`.